# encode path of nested javascript object

Tags: javascript, json, recursion, tree, nested

I want to write a function that takes a nested json object and writes a `path` array in each of objects that denote the "path" or hierarchy of the object itself. the `path` array should be populated by the `id` of the parent nodes. the limits array objects should have a path and since they don't have an id, an enumarated key is given to them based on the index in that array. my attempt is below however I am not getting the correct path at certain nth levels down.

```js
let nestedObject = {
    "name":"bob",
    "root_rule":{
       "id":0,
       "limits":[
          {
             "value":0
          }
       ],
       "rules":[
          {
             "id":15,
             "limits":[
                
             ],
             "rules":[
                
             ]
          },
          {
             "id":16,
             "limits":[
                {
                   "value":25000000
                },
                {
                   "value":50001
                },
                {
                   "value":25000001
                }
             ],
             "rules":[
                {
                   "id":20,
                   "limits":[
                      {
                         "value":0
                      }
                   ],
                   "rules":[
                      {
                         "id":21,
                         "limits":[
                            
                         ],
                         "rules":[
                            
                         ]
                      }
                   ]
                }
             ]
          }
       ]
    }
 }
function encodeNestedPath(nestedJson, pathList, type, parent = null) {

    // process rood node
    if ((typeof nestedJson) == 'object') {
        
        if(nestedJson && nestedJson.condition && nestedJson.condition.name === 'ROOT') {
            nestedJson['path'] = [String(nestedJson['id'])];
        }
        
        if(nestedJson.limits) {
            encodeNestedPath(nestedJson.limits, nestedJson['path'], 'limits', nestedJson['id']);
        }
        if(nestedJson.rules) {
            encodeNestedPath(nestedJson.rules, nestedJson['path'], 'rules', nestedJson['id']);
        }
    }

    // traverse children nodes
    if (Array.isArray(nestedJson)) {
        for (const [i, element] of nestedJson.entries()) {

            element['path'] = [];

            if(String(parent)) {
                element['path'].push(String(parent))
            }

            let parentId
            if(!element.hasOwnProperty('id')) {
                element['path'].push(type+'_'+i)
                pathList = null
            } else {
                element['path'].push(String(element['id']))
                parentId = element['id']
            }

            if(element.limits) {
                encodeNestedPath(element.limits, element['path'], 'limits', parentId);
            }
            if(element.rules) {
                encodeNestedPath(element.rules, element['path'], 'rules', parentId);
            }
        }
    }
}



encodeNestedPath(nestedObject['root_rule'], null, null, null)
console.log(JSON.stringify(nestedObject['root_rule'], null, 4))
```

Desiring output is like this.
[image: image of desired output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the issues in your function is that you don't do anything useful with the `pathList` argument. Instead, you start building a path from scratch with:

```
nestedJson['path'] = [String(nestedJson['id'])];
```

and with:

```
element['path'] = [];
```

where the latter is followed by a single push.

In essence all your `path` properties are set to arrays of length 1.

Here is an implementation that iterates through the object hierarchy (without special treatment for hardcoded properties like `limits` or `rules`) and applies the logic you described:

```js
function encodeNestedPath(obj, pathList=[], parentKey) {
    if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
         // remove plural and append underscore
        parentKey = parentKey !== undefined ? parentKey.replace(/s?$/, "_") : "";
        obj.forEach((elem, i) => encodeNestedPath(elem, pathList, parentKey + i));
    } else if (Object(obj) === obj) {
        if ("id" in obj) parentKey = obj.id;
        if (parentKey !== undefined) pathList = pathList.concat(parentKey);
        if (pathList.length) obj.path = pathList
        for (let prop in obj) encodeNestedPath(obj[prop], pathList, prop);
    }
}

// object from the question:
let nestedObject = {"name": "bob","root_rule":{"id":0,"limits":[{"value":0}],"rules":[{"id":15,"limits":[],"rules":[]},{"id":16,"limits":[{"value":25000000},{"value":50001},{"value":25000001}],"rules":[{"id":20,"limits":[{"value":0}],"rules":[{"id":21,"limits":[],"rules":[]}]}]}]}};

encodeNestedPath(nestedObject);
console.log(nestedObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a big fan of reinventing the wheel. I'd recommend you use a library for the basics. We use [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan) for all our data processing these days. It's powerful once you wrap your head around how to use it. Here is how you'd use it to solve your questions:

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script type="module">
import objectScan from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/object-scan@18.1.2/lib/index.min.js';

const process = (data) => objectScan(['**.id', '**.limits[*]'], {
  rtn: 'bool',
  filterFn: ({ value, parents, property }) => {
    const path = parents.filter((p) => 'id' in p).map(({ id }) => id).reverse();
    if (property === 'id') {
      parents[0].path = path;
    } else {
      value.path = path.concat(`limit_${property}`);
    }
  }
})(data);

const data = { name: 'bob', root_rule: { id: 0, limits: [{ value: 0 }], rules: [{ id: 15, limits: [], rules: [] }, { id: 16, limits: [{ value: 25000000 }, { value: 50001 }, { value: 25000001 }], rules: [{ id: 20, limits: [{ value: 0 }], rules: [{ id: 21, limits: [], rules: [] }] }] }] } };

console.log(process(data)); // returns true iff match
// => true

console.log(data);
// => { name: 'bob', root_rule: { id: 0, limits: [ { value: 0, path: [ 0, 'limit_0' ] } ], rules: [ { id: 15, limits: [], rules: [], path: [ 0, 15 ] }, { id: 16, limits: [ { value: 25000000, path: [ 0, 16, 'limit_0' ] }, { value: 50001, path: [ 0, 16, 'limit_1' ] }, { value: 25000001, path: [ 0, 16, 'limit_2' ] } ], rules: [ { id: 20, limits: [ { value: 0, path: [ 0, 16, 20, 'limit_0' ] } ], rules: [ { id: 21, limits: [], rules: [], path: [ 0, 16, 20, 21 ] } ], path: [ 0, 16, 20 ] } ], path: [ 0, 16 ] } ], path: [ 0 ] } }
</script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)

Alternative way that gives you more control

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script type="module">
import objectScan from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/object-scan@18.1.2/lib/index.min.js';

const process = (data) => {
  const extractPath = (parents) => parents
    .filter((p) => 'id' in p)
    .map(({ id }) => id)
    .reverse();
  const logic = {
    '**.id': ({ parents }) => {
      parents[0].path = extractPath(parents);
    },
    '**.limits[*]': ({ value, parents, property }) => {
      value.path = [...extractPath(parents), `limit_${property}`];
    }
  };
  return objectScan(Object.keys(logic), {
    rtn: 'bool',
    filterFn: (kwargs) => kwargs.matchedBy.forEach((n) => logic[n](kwargs))
  })(data);
};

const data = { name: 'bob', root_rule: { id: 0, limits: [{ value: 0 }], rules: [{ id: 15, limits: [], rules: [] }, { id: 16, limits: [{ value: 25000000 }, { value: 50001 }, { value: 25000001 }], rules: [{ id: 20, limits: [{ value: 0 }], rules: [{ id: 21, limits: [], rules: [] }] }] }] } };

console.log(process(data));
// => true

console.log(data);
// => { name: 'bob', root_rule: { id: 0, limits: [ { value: 0, path: [ 0, 'limit_0' ] } ], rules: [ { id: 15, limits: [], rules: [], path: [ 0, 15 ] }, { id: 16, limits: [ { value: 25000000, path: [ 0, 16, 'limit_0' ] }, { value: 50001, path: [ 0, 16, 'limit_1' ] }, { value: 25000001, path: [ 0, 16, 'limit_2' ] } ], rules: [ { id: 20, limits: [ { value: 0, path: [ 0, 16, 20, 'limit_0' ] } ], rules: [ { id: 21, limits: [], rules: [], path: [ 0, 16, 20, 21 ] } ], path: [ 0, 16, 20 ] } ], path: [ 0, 16 ] } ], path: [ 0 ] } }
</script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)